# Matlab Matrix multiplication ignoring nans?

Tags: matlab, matrix, nan

I have two matrices `A` and `B` which I want to multiply, but they contain `nan`s.

The default multiply puts `nan` down the whole column of the result where there was even a single `nan` in the data. I want to ignore them, like `nansum`/`nanmean` etc do. In other words, instead of computing

```
 sum( A(i,j) * B(j,k) )
```

I want it to use `nansum`.

I suppose this is possible by replacing `nan` with `0`, and then multiplying, but the point of having `nansum` is to obviate that, right?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason the multiplication results in `NaN`s is that there is no one true way in which they should be handled. If, in your case, they should be replaced by zero, it's easiest to write

```
A(isnan(A)) = 0;
```

before running the multiplication. I would advise against re-writing matrix multiplication, since you won't get similar performance to built-in matrix algebra out of your own code.

`nansum`, and particularly `nanmean` etc are functions of the statistics toolbox where `NaN`s aren't simply replaced by zero, but actually removed from the calculation, because in the context of statistics, `NaN` is used to indicate missing data points. There is no `nanmult` out there, because in statistics, you don't often matrix-multiply, and if you do (e.g. within a regression), having a single observation missing from a vector usually means that you'll want to throw out the entire row/column, anyway.

Comment: +1: If replacing `NaN`s at all, however, I'd consider replacing them _after_ multiplying the matrices. This, at least, allows identifying the elements in the result which don't rely on missing values. Then again, it all depends on what one wants to achieve.

Comment: Thanks guys, point taken; ignoring nan is a case-specific need. I'm trying to multiply `eig(nancov(X))'` by `X` to estimate a matrix with PCA, except `X` contains missing values. I think in this context, `nan-->0` makes sense?

Answer (score 1):

```
import numpy as np

#find the dimensions of your arrays
sza=a.shape
szb=b.shape

#calculate by using nested loops rows of 'a' times columns of 'b'
c=np.zeros(sza[0],szb[1])
for i in range(0, sza[0]):
  for k in range(0, szb[1]):
    c[i, k]=np.nansum(a[i, ]*b[:, k])
```

Comment: `python` is not tagged in the question

Comment: Can explain why your solution works in order raise the value of your contribution?

Comment: The basic idea of matrix multiplication is to sum the products of the rows of matrix A[sza[0], sza[1]] by the columns of B[szb[0], szb[1]], where sza[1] = szb[0]. In my nested loop format I run through every column of B for each row of A. I find the products and only sum on the products that produce a real number (eg 1*nan=nan therefore this will be ignored and not added) I enter the sum in to matrix c that has already been defined in the proper dimension (sza[0], szb[1]).